# retrieve data from the database but the result of " array"

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I tried to call up data from the model , but when running the results in view the word " array" . is there who can help me ? i am using codeigniter

Controller

```
$data=array('pengunjung' => $this->mcrud->jumlah_visitor(),
            'isi'        =>'user/monitoring');
$this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
```

Model

```
function jumlah_visitor() {
    $date = date("Ymd");

    $this->db->where('date',$date);
    $this->db->group_by(array('ip'));           
    $ambil= $this->db->get('tbcounter');
    if ($ambil->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($ambil->result_array() as $data) {
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }   
}
```

View

```
<div class="pull-left">Hari Ini : </div>
<div class="pull-right number"> <?php echo $pengunjung; ?></div>
```

Result

> Hari ini : array

Comment: `$this->mcrud->jumlah_visitor()` returns an array as you have defined over there in your method, treat it as such, loop over when needed

Answer (score 1):

First you check the return value of `$this->mcrud->jumlah_visitor()` after that you print the value. If it's an array you have to use loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $pengunjung; ?>
```

to

```
<?php print_r($pengunjung); ?>
```

`$pengunjung` variable is array not string variable

Answer (score 0):

Yes of-course... 
in your `Model` you are returning an array

```
 foreach ($ambil->result_array() as $data) {
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
```

The same you are trying to catch in your `controller`  `$this->mcrud->jumlah_visitor(),`
 return your `index-key` just like `$data->index_key`

Try printing array as `pengunjung` is holding `an array`, not a simple `variable`.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->mcrud->jumlah_visitor);
echo "</pre>";
```

You will get complete array info.

Comment: thanks @Vijay Sai Chaudary, but not work still the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo an array. you should use a loop to display result of $pengunjung.
In View just use

`foreach( $pengunjung as $key => $value)
{
//echo $value;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your model function like this

```
function jumlah_visitor() {
    $date = date("Ymd");

    $this->db->where('date',$date);
    $this->db->group_by(array('ip'));           
    $ambil= $this->db->get('tbcounter');
     $data = $ambil->result_array();
    if (data->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($data as $data1) {
            $hasil[] = $data1;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }   
}
```